# How to bind name attribute of a radio button in knockout

Tags: html, asp.net, knockout.js

I have this code in my ASP.Net project which is using knockout.js:

```
<div>
     <input type="radio" name="hearingAidConditionGroup" value="Yes" data-bind="checked: condition">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="radio" name="hearingAidConditionGroup" value="No" data-bind="checked: condition">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;No&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

which is stored in a file called `a.cshtml`, I have another html file which includes this one like:

```
<div data-bind="with: testConditions()[0]">
    <h4>Test conditions</h4>
    @Html.Partial("~/a.cshtml")
</div>
<div data-bind="with: testConditions()[1]">
    <h4>Second test conditions</h4>
    @Html.Partial("~/a.cshtml")
</div>
```

in my js file I have:

```
this.testConditions = ko.observableArray([
        { condition: "Yes" },
        { condition: "Yes" }
    ]);
```

so the question is how I can differentiate the radio buttons as with the above code all the radio buttons in my form have the same name and basically selecting one of them at the div including `testConditions()[0]` affects the other ones in the div including `testConditions()[1]` and vice versa.

I was thinking to add a second properties in the array like:

```
this.testConditions = ko.observableArray([
            { condition: "Yes", itemname: "group1" },
            { condition: "Yes", itemname: "group2" }
        ]);
```

and used that in html like:

```
 <div>
     <input type="radio" value="Yes" data-bind="checked: condition, name: itemname">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="radio" value="No" data-bind="checked: condition, name: itemname">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;No&nbsp;</label>
 </div>
```

however, it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<div>
 <input type="radio" value="Yes" data-bind="checked: condition, attr: { 'name': itemname}">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;</label>
 <input type="radio" value="No" data-bind="checked: condition, attr: { 'name': itemname}">&nbsp;<label class="YesNo">&nbsp;No&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to group like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="a"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="b"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="c"><br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="x"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="y"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="z">
```

when form is submitted 
radiobutton[0] = "a";
radiobutton[1] = "x";

OR

try 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chandirasekaranid/fgqkjenc/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am really keen to have a modular code, yes it is always possible to have all radio buttons in the html file which requires massive coding just imagine I have 1000 different testConditions

Comment: updated here https://jsfiddle.net/chandirasekaranid/fgqkjenc/